# [JavaFX]Check every single CheckBoxTreeItem if selected

Tags: java, javafx

I need to check every single item in my `CheckBoxTreeItem` root.

At the moment I can only check the root Item but not their children.

```
public class Controller{


    @FXML Button button;



    @FXML
    private void press(MouseEvent event){

            System.out.println("Hello");

            System.out.println(checkBoxTreeItem.isSelected());

    }

     @FXML
     private TreeView<String> treeview;
     private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem;

     private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem;

     public void viewListFill() {
     rootItem.setExpanded(true);
     System.out.print("hhhhhh");
     treeview.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView());

     checkBoxTreeItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem("Völkerwanderung");
     rootItem.getChildren().add(checkBoxTreeItem);

     System.out.println( rootItem.isIndependent());


     checkBoxTreeItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("b");
     rootItem.getChildren().add(checkBoxTreeItem);
     }


     public void initialize() {
     rootItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("A");
     treeview.setRoot(rootItem);
     }

}
```

I cant find anything into the oracle doc.
I have red about a call back and `observableValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `rootItem` is the parent for a given number of items, you just need to go through them to check their status. Something like this:

```
private boolean checkAllItemsSelected(){
    for(TreeItem item:rootItem.getChildren()){
        if(!((CheckBoxTreeItem)item).isSelected()){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In case of a multilevel tree, you could create a recursive method.

**EDIT**

If you just need to know if any of the items is selected this will return the number of them selected, printing on the console their name:

```
private int checkItemsSelected(){
    int count=0;
    for(TreeItem item:rootItem.getChildren()){
        if(((CheckBoxTreeItem)item).isSelected()){
            count++;
            System.out.println("item: "+item.getValue().toString());
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

And if you are looking for some concrete item:

```
private boolean checkItemIsSelected(String name){
    for(TreeItem item:rootItem.getChildren()){
        if(item.getValue().toString().equals(name)){
            return ((CheckBoxTreeItem)item).isSelected();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hello Pereda, at first thx for your answer. But it seems my explanation was not accurately. I need to check if any Checkbox is selected. With your code, it is only true, if every singel children is selected or root(that auto select all). But i need to find out which of the checkboxes are selected.

Comment: With "every single item" I thought you need all of them. If you just need to find if any of them is selected, and which one just modify the function... I'll edit my answer

Comment: Shame on me! String comparing i dont got that idea. Thank very much for your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

at first thx for your answer. But it seems my explanation was not accurately. I need to check if any Checkbox is selected. With your code, it is only true, if every singel children is selected or root(that auto select all). But i need to find out which of the checkboxes are selected.

```
public class Controller{

@FXML Button button;

@FXML
private void press(MouseEvent event){

        System.out.println("Hallo");
        System.out.println("Es ist selektiert: " +checkAllItemsSelected());
}

private boolean checkAllItemsSelected(){
    for(TreeItem item:rootItem.getChildren()){
        if(!((CheckBoxTreeItem)item).isSelected()){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

 @FXML
 private TreeView<String> treeview;
 private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem;
 private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem;

 public void initialize() {

     rootItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Root Check");
     treeview.setRoot(rootItem);
     viewListFill();
}

 public void viewListFill() {

rootItem.setExpanded(true);
treeview.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView());

checkBoxTreeItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem("Check 1");
rootItem.getChildren().add(checkBoxTreeItem);

checkBoxTreeItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Check 2");
rootItem.getChildren().add(checkBoxTreeItem);


}
```

}